# Clear input field after click without attach any external script

Tags: 7, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

Are there any helper functions contained in **Drupal core or Ctools** to perform popular tasks such as clearing input field after an event occurs ?
I know how to do it using external **js** (javascript) file, but I was wondering whether an alternative way for this exists or not  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt it, that would be re-inventing the wheel IMO...what you're describing is pretty much what jQuery is for. Consider this code, which is a basic representation of what you're trying to do:

```
$(function() {
  $('#some-element').bind('someEvent', function() {
    $('#some-other-element').val('');
  });
});
```

That's only 3 meaningful lines of code, and is so trivial that writing a function to wrap around it would be counter-intuitive. The resulting code would end up being equally or more verbose, and all it would do is basically pass parameters blindly to a jQuery function.

Don't forget if you want to invoke any Javascript at all you're going to need an external JS file (or at the very least inline code). I would suggest using the above 3 lines in that external/inline JS would be preferable to using any sort of wrapper function (even if one does exist).

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your question 'Clear input field after click without attach any external script', possibly this will work ::

1. Consider the url http://campusdiaries.com/
2. Here, consider Email & School/College/Org fields on home page (for registration)

Here, we have used below form elements ::

'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Email'))
'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('School/College/Org'))

Here, input field gets cleaned on mouse down.

Hope it helps.